# display xslt with xslt

Tags: xslt

I would like to display my xslt with a general xslt in order to generate a documentation on how the xslt is built. I got some help here on stackoverflow, but there are still some details I thought I managed to do myself, but unfortunatley not.

Previous post: [Generate xsl documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304459/generate-xsl-documentation)

This is how I would like it to work:

My xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <head>
        <title>My sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        My sample element: <xsl:value-of select="root/element1"/>     
    </body>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The requested output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        My sample element: root/element1
    </body>
</html>
```

If possible, Id also like to display for-each loops and if statements. Has anyone done this and could share som code with me?

Comment: As soon as you have multiple templates an not just the `/` (root) template things get hairy, because they depend on the input only. This doesn't seem to be an appropriate way of documenting the stylesheet.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to be able to design different xslt:s for my XML format and to make things easier generate a documentation for each xslt on the fly. Do you see any other possible solutions to generate xslt doc. on the fly? Im using PHP on the server side.

Comment: You haven't defined what "documentation" is. Until this happens the question is quite ambiguous and allows very wide ranging interpretation. I agree with @Lucero that the current output's usefulness is negative.

Comment: Any documentation that can be generated on fly on my xslt (using PHP or an external xslt) would be great. Therefore I have no clear definition of "documentation" but are instead grateful for any solution that would generate any documentation on the fly (using PHP or an external xslt). Thanks.

Comment: What Dimitre said: we'd like to help, but we don't understand what you want as a result of transforming your XSLT.  FWIW, there are already documentation generators out there for XSLT that are based on XSLT transforms, e.g. OxygenXML's built in tool.

Answer (score 1):

**I have  done some changes, I think it can help you, plz check code and run it on your input XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    >
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
           <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
           </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', name())" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" />
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/', name(), '&gt;')" />
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', name(), '=&quot;', ., '&quot;')" />
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="xsl:*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsl:value-of">
        <xsl:value-of select="@select" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- add appropriate templates for the other XSLT elements -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```